# Rust, what decides a function name is a fn pointer to fn item?

Tags: rust, fn

Here is the code that works.

```rust
use core::future::Future;

async fn haha(ctx: u8) -> u8 {
    return 2u8;
}

fn set_func<T>(path: &'static str, f: fn(u8) -> T) -> u8
where
    T: Future<Output = u8> + Send + 'static,
{
    return 8u8;
}

fn main() {
  set_func("haha", haha);
}
```

but when I change the haha function to

```rust
use core::future::Future;

async fn haha(ctx: &mut u8) -> u8 {
    return 2u8;
}

fn set_func<T>(path: &'static str, f: fn(&mut u8) -> T) -> u8
where
    T: Future<Output = u8> + Send + 'static,
{
    return 8u8;
}

fn main() {
  set_func("haha", haha);
}
```

Then error will shows like this:

```
   |
13 |     set_func("haha", haha);
   |     --------         ^^^^ one type is more general than the other
   |     |
   |     arguments to this function are incorrect
   |
   = note: expected fn pointer `for<'a> fn(&'a mut u8) -> _`
                 found fn item `for<'a> fn(&'a mut u8) -> impl Future<Output = u8> {haha}`
```

I am so confusing that changing a argument from `u8` to `&mut u8` will change the `fn pointer` to `fn item`. why this happen?
and the `&mut u8` is a requirement, do you have anyway can keep the `&mut u8` and make it pass the type check?

Comment: I'm not totally sure why but if you specify the lifetime of the reference in `set_func()` it compiles: [playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=6562330b3eaab3d1712f35de2dbe237a).

Comment: @rodrigo It essentially infers the lifetime to be `'static`. It fails with any temporary value. What happens is that instead of the default desugaring of HRTB, it can assume `'static`.

Comment: @ChayimFriedman: Also if you change the `haha` function to assert that it returns an static future it also works, probably more faithful to the OP intention: `fn haha(ctx: &mut u8) -> impl Future<Output = u8> { async move { 2u8 } }`.

Comment: I finally using the BoxedFuture solution. which is describe in here https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=eb8150468d05cc351d468b41a16d2693

Comment: However, I got a lot more lifetime problem for my crate, which something like I know it will be safe but I just failed to tell the Rust compiler as I don't know the special way to tell it. it's very frustrated